# Suppose [something] than [something]?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

[image: Moral Foundations of Politics]

In given text I don't understand what does **than** belong to.
**Suppose**? If not, and if it belongs to **any more**, then what does **any more** means in this context?

Comment: There is no reason to suppose _that there is an ideal private realm beyond conflict_ any more than [there is reason to suppose that] _there is one in the traditions of some distant past_.

Comment: thank you very much